# Add tag synonym for ultimate

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can someone add [ultimate-frisbee](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-frisbee) as synonym for [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate)? According to many references, "frisbee" is omitted due to trademark concerns, yet ultimate frisbee is a commonly used name for the sport.

Comment: "frisbee" is omitted because it's not the name of the sport. It would be like calling "Curling" "Rock Curling"

Comment: @sancho, I came across the game/sport a long time ago - back then, everyone I knew called it "ultimate frisbee."

Comment: Ah... yes. It was previously more often called ultimate frisbee, but the newer generation of players has grown up knowing it under the simple name "ultimate". Definitely worth a tag synonym.

Comment: Tag synonym has been added. Question closed.

Answer (score 0):

"Ultimate" is also used as a synonym for "ultimate running" - usually everything longer than a Marathon - so I don't think we can add the requested synonym...

**UPPS**: I have just noticed that I read the question the wrong way around. Hmm... I would like to do away with the "ultimate" tag all-together... :-)

Comment: Not even if the sport itself is called "ultimate" now?

Comment: My point is that we have two sports that calls itself "ultimate"... It is much like the discussion we had previously on the tag "football"...

Comment: I don't agree. Ultimate running might be informally called "ultra" or "ultimate", but ultimate frisbee is literally referenced as "ultimate" now.