# "Ultimate" is which sport?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate) today refers to "Ultimate Frisbee", and there are actually a request to add [ultimate-frisbee](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-frisbee) as a synonym for [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate) - see [Add tag synonym for ultimate](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/38).

The problem is that "Ultimate" also is the everyday name for "Ultimate Running".

In order to avoid any confusion, I would sugest to do a simple rename of [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate) to [ultimate-frisbee](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-frisbee) and then keep [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate) unassigned.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimate is and should be referenced with [ultimate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate) not [ultimate-frisbee](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-frisbee). Just like disc golf it referenced [disc-golf](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc-golf) and not [frisbee-golf](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frisbee-golf).

Ultimate running should be referenced (if we get a question on it, which we so far do not even have one) with [ultimate-running](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-running). Or we could use the other term for it [ultra](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra) or [ultra-running](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-running).

Both of these options are better than deciding that we should integrate the branding that the ultimate folks are now trying to hard to avoid. (Referencing it as "Ultimate Frisbee" would be rather narrow sited as "Frisbee" is a rather specific brand name. Most flying discs are now made by several other companies at this point (Discraft, Innova, Wham-O (makers of the iconic "Frisbee)). While the branding is part of the common parlance there is little reason anymore with other manufacturers making very good flying discs. (This is very similar to how Disc Golf has fought against the "Frisbee Golf" name).

Comment: In fact, a good deal of the country associations around this sport - whatever the name - seems to use the term "flying disc" :-)

Comment: I don't expect a larger number of ultimate running related questions, but I always like to keep the names strait for the beginning, so we are not going to have this fight later when/if the questions come...

Answer (score 2):

Ultimate is the name of a sport that uses a flying disc. Ultimate frisbee isn't the name of a sport.

Comment: And likewise "Ultimate" is the name of a sport where you run 50+ km :-)

Comment: Until you brought it up in this question, "Ultimate" have always been running to me :-) I can see the web that "Ultimate" primary is used in English speaking countries, whereas "Frisbee" is used almost everywhere else (see http://www.efdf.org/european.assoc.html). I can also see that WikiPedia agrees with you - although almost all references there are for US and Canada :-) I'll check for reference for ultimate == running tonight...